# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) when trying to run Queue program - C++

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, queue

I keep getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error every time I try to run my code with g++ on Linux. It compiles fine, but then that happens ... All the functions (remove, add and print) seem to have the same problem, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong... Please heeeelppp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Create a node struct
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
};

class Queue {
private:
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int size;
public:
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  void add(int d);
  int remove();
  bool isEmpty();
  void printQueue(bool o);
};


//set to NULL
Queue::Queue() {

  head = tail = NULL;
  size = 0;

}

//destructor
//call remove until empty
Queue::~Queue() {

  while (!isEmpty())
    remove();
}

//adds a node with the given data at the back of the queue
void Queue::add(int d) {

  Node *temp = new Node();
  temp->data = d;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if (isEmpty()) {

    //add to head
    head = temp;

  } else {

    //append
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;

    cout << "Added: " << tail->data << endl;
  }

  size++;
}

//removes the node at the head of the queue and returns its data
int Queue::remove() {

  if (isEmpty()) {

    cout << "The queue is empty." << endl;

  } else {

    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp = head;
    int value = head->data;

    //moves pointer to next node
    head = head->next;

    cout << "Removed: " << head->data << endl;

    size--;
    delete temp;
    return value;

  }
}

//determines if the queue is empty
bool Queue::isEmpty() {
  return (size == 0);
}

//prints the contents of the queue from front to back, or front
//to back, depending on the value of the parameter
void Queue::printQueue(bool o) {

  if (isEmpty()) {

    cout << "The queue is empty." << endl;

  } else {

    Node *p = new Node;

    if (o == true) {

      cout << "Printing in front to back:" << endl;

      //print front to back
      while(p != NULL) {
        p = head;
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
      }

    } else if (o == false) {

      cout << "Printing in back to front:" << endl;

      //print back to front
      while (p != NULL) {
        p = tail;
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->prev;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {

  Queue q;

  q.add(8);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've made some changes to the code... But I'm still getting the same error. I assume I'm not updating the head and the tail and/or the next and prev nodes correctly... I don't know why it's wrong or what I'm missing, though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
};

class Queue {
private:
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int size;
public:
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  void add(int d);
  int remove();
  bool isEmpty();
  void printQueue(bool o);
};

Queue::Queue() {

  head = tail = NULL;
  size = 0;

}

Queue::~Queue() {

  while (!isEmpty())
    remove();
}

void Queue::add(int d) {

  Node *temp = new Node;
  temp->data = d;
  temp->next = NULL;
  temp->prev = tail;

  if (isEmpty()) {

    //add to head
    head = temp;

  } else {

    //append
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;

    cout << "Added: " << tail->data << endl;
  }
  size++;
}

int Queue::remove() {

  if (isEmpty()) {

    cout << "The queue is empty." << endl;

    return 0;

  } else {

    Node *temp = head;
    int value = head->data;

    cout << "Removed: " << head->data << endl;

    //moves pointer to next node
    head = head->next;
    head->prev = NULL;

    size--;
    delete temp;
    return value;
  }
}

bool Queue::isEmpty() {
  return (size == 0);
}

void Queue::printQueue(bool o) {

  if (isEmpty()) {

    cout << "The queue is empty." << endl;

  } else {

    Node *p;

    if (o == true) {

      p = head;

      cout << "Printing in front to back:" << endl;

      //print front to back
      while(p != NULL) {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
      }

    } else if (o == false) {

      p = tail;

      cout << "Printing in back to front:" << endl;

      //print back to front
      while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->prev;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {

  Queue q;

  q.add(9);
  q.add(10);
  q.add(11);
  q.add(12);
  q.add(13);
  q.add(14);
  q.add(15);
  q.add(16);

  q.remove();
  q.remove();

  q.printQueue(true);
  q.printQueue(false);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, Insta-Memory Leak: `Node *temp = new Node; temp = ...`. This isn't Java. Related: ` head = head->next;` followed by sending `head->data` to `cout` isn't going to end well when `head` *was* the last node in queue. `head->data` dereferences a null pointer, which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of problems:

1. You have a double-linked `Node` but never update its `prev` member in the add/remove methods.
2. You are keeping track of both the `Queue` head/tail but don't properly update them when you add/remove nodes.
3. Both your forward and reverse loops in `printQueue()` are wrong and result in an infinite loop for any queue with 2 or more elements. Queue output should be just something like:

   ```
   Node *p = head;

   while (p != NULL) 
   {
       cout << p->data << " ";
       p = p->next;
   }
   ```
4. Possible `null` pointer deference in `remove()` at `cout << "Removed: " << head->data << endl;` since you've already moved the `head` pointer by this time. Move the `head` after the `cout`.
5. Memory leak in `Queue::remove()` at `Node *temp = new Node;`. Just do `Node* temp = head;`.
6. Memory leak in `Queue::printQueue()` at `Node *p = new Node;`. You don't need to allocate a node here.
7. No return value in `remove()` for an empty queue.

**Edit**

Don't forget to initialize the `tail` when adding a node to an empty list:

```
if (isEmpty()) {
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;
}
```

To remove a node from the head of a non-empty list it should be something like:

```
Node *temp = head;
head = head->next;
if (head) head->prev = NULL;
size--;
delete temp;
if (isEmpty()) tail = NULL;
```